# Initializing a member array's size with another member within the class

Tags: c++, class, object

Here is my code

```
class world{
public:
    int w;
    int h;
    int windowWidth = 80;
    int windowHeight = 46;
    char windowMap[windowHeight][windowWidth];
```

I want to make the size of windowMap[46][80] by using windowWidth and windowHeight but I get this error

> warning: non-static data member initializers only available with
>   -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

is there a way to fix this or a better way of achieving the same results?

Comment: If you think it is about the array, remove it and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables for width and height must be constant and static, since they should be available during compile time. Otherwise, you could use a vector and allocate the memory dynamically in the constructor. Then you could specify the size of the windowMap as arguments, thus making the class more reusable.

The simple changes are:

```
const static int windowWidth = 80;
const static int windowHeight = 46;
```

Answer (score 1):

This question <strike>is</strike> *was* marked as C++11, this **is** allowed in C++11 (even the warning indicates that). So a way to fix this would be to add the `-std=c++11` compiler flag (which would be my recommendation if possible to do so)

N1ckles's answer is probably the best one otherwise, just if you use the dynamic allocation method proposed by OwnageIsMagic, don't forget that you must call delete[] in the destructor!

Answer (score 0):

Move `windowMap` field initialization to constructor

```
class world{
public:
    int w;
    int h;
    int windowWidth = 80;
    int windowHeight = 46;
    char **windowMap;
    world (){
        windowMap = new char*[windowWidth];
        for(int i = 0; i < windowWidth; i++)
            windowMap[i] = new char[windowHeight];
    }
};
```

Declaring field as `static` will share it across all instaces of this class, that probably not preferd in this situation.

**Don't** forget that you have to call delete[] in the destructor or you have a memory leak.